# How to calculate the total area of all bodies/shapes on the screen

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I'm trying to calculate the total area all bodies or shapes are occupying on the screen. I.e. if I have 2 circles, A and B, that intersect each other, I want to calculate the area that A union B covers (on the screen).

I've been reading through the chipmunk [documentation](http://files.slembcke.net/chipmunk/release/ChipmunkLatest-Docs/) and looked in the chipmunk [API](http://chipmunk-physics.net/release/Objective-ChipmunkLatest-Docs/annotated.html) for a method that I might use, but I haven't found anything that I can use directly.

The only two methods I found, that might be useful, are these two: [`pointQueryFirst:layers:group:`](http://chipmunk-physics.net/release/Objective-ChipmunkLatest-Docs/interface_chipmunk_space.html#af41855579653620ce5310f9ce8887bef) and [`segmentQueryFirstFrom:to:layers:group:`](http://chipmunk-physics.net/release/Objective-ChipmunkLatest-Docs/interface_chipmunk_space.html#a068267fad09180f4bd0d484401ebad41)

The way I was thinking was to:

- Use the first method (pointQueryFirst) to go through all points on the screen and call this method. If a point doesn't have a shape in them, then accumulate it to a variable. Then divide that variable value with the area of the screen to get percentage of the screen that is free.
- Or use the second method (segmentQueryFirstFrom), create an recursive algorithm that divides the screen in half and run the query on each half, if any half contains a shape, then divide that area into halves and check if those contains any shapes, and so on...

But I expect that in using them, the overall performance will suffer. Is there another solution that I can use? Another method that I haven't found? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Chipmunk isn't particularly going to be able to help you with that. The methods you mentioned will work, but be ridiculously slow.

I think I would do a good old fashioned occlusion query. Render the shapes into a texture or some sort of offscreen buffer and then count the pixels.

Comment: I am new to objective-c, cocos2d, chipmunk. Any suggestions on which classes to use? Thereafter I can look it up in the API.

Comment: Make a CCRenderTexture, then read back the pixel data using glReadPixels(). Keep in mind that this is *not* fast. It's going to take tens of milliseconds to read back the pixels from the GPU so you don't want to do this every frame.